# MSBuild tries to copy files overwritten as part of the PreBuildEvent

Tags: c#, .net, build, msbuild, csproj

When I'm building the application, one of the PreBuildEvents is the build of the React front-end:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <PreBuildEvent>
        powershell.exe "npm --prefix """$(ProjectDir)Scripts\client""" run build"   
    </PreBuildEvent>
 </PropertyGroup>
```

Which overwrites the `Project\Scripts\client\build`

As part of the build I include the build folder in the project:

```
<Content Include="Scripts\client\build\**" />
```

However, towards the end of the build, I get an error:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v16.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets(182,5): 
error MSB3030: Could not copy the file "Scripts\client\build\precache-manifest.639e62e5c73567fc96d77fd52068e2d7.js" 
because it was not found.
```

The problem is that the `Scripts\client\build\precache-manifest.639e62e5c73567fc96d77fd52068e2d7.js` was the file in the build folder before the PreBuildEvent was executed, after the PreBuildEvent was run the file is `Scripts\client\build\precache-manifest.9fab5f56d5c8f9561b6f289e96f4a80e.js`.

This problem just randomly started to happen recently, and seems to persist even if the entire repo is reverted 50+ versions back, and the issue is replicable across multiple computers running different versions of Visual Studio (2017 & 2019)

Comment: Your example for `PreBuildEvent` is a property definition. There is a `PreBuildEvent` target (provided by Microsoft.Common.targets) which can be overridden. Does your project have an override of the `PreBuildEvent` target that is using the `PreBuildEvent` property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like the `Include` to the `Content` item group is being handled before the React build. Move the `Include` to a target that executes after the React build to ensure that the newly generated files are picked up.

If you have something like the following in the 'top level' of your project, the files will be added to the `Content` item collection before any targets have run -- which is not what you want.

```xml
<ItemGroup>
  <Content Include="Scripts\client\build\**" />
</ItemGroup>
```

How best to include the files after the React build, depends a bit on how the React build is actually being done.

Comment: hi Johnathan, I have moved my build into a custom target, and set DefaultTargets to first run the react build target, and only then the Build step. However, the issue persists, I still get an error that the file is missing. It seems that there's a file system scan that takes place even before any of the targets start executing (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-targets?view=vs-2019)

Comment: Is the `<Content Include="Scripts\client\build\**" />` within a target? If it is not within a target, it will always be done before any target has run. 'Top level' Items are done in the [Evaluation Phase](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/build-process-overview?view=vs-2019#evaluation-phase).

Comment: you are right, the content include is not within a target, I thought that the top-level items are evaluated as part of the build target. I'll test moving it to a custom target and see if that fixes it. is it safe to move everything in the top level to a target?

Comment: Top-level items are not a part of any target. No, it is not safe to move everything in the top level to a target. That will change the order of when things are defined and available. The reason for putting the Include of the React files in a target is to explicitly delay the evaluation of the Include until after the React build has been performed. The Include doesn't need its own target. If you have a 'BuildReact' target, you could add the Include within that target after the build command. Your example code shows a PropertyGroup and doesn't show how the React build is actually done.